# Copy Command Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, pentaho, amazon-redshift, kettle

Is there any way to output the number of rows copied while executing a copy command in redshift.

From aws states that the data is available in stl_load_commits, but gives a warning  that data may not be alway correct.

I'm looking for more reliable data. I'm also using kettle to run this copy command, so if there a way to get the result from kettle - that method would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you create a job (not a transformation) and use Kettle's built in copy step it will report the number of files copied to you.

Yea, I think there's a "Add files to result files name" setting on that step which you can further use with kettle to figure out anything you want.